# Find self position by knowing four points and three angles

Tags: coordinate-systems

Assume we are working in 2D and each point has (x,y) coordinates.

We want to find our position P(x,y)
We know the coordinates of points A, B, C and D.
We know angles (APB), (APC), (APD)

This is a math problem in artillery related to finding self positioning. Can anyone suggest a formula for that?